# Include duplicate MIT licenses for every project even if my code base is available in GitHub?

Tags: licensing, mit

I use three MIT licensed projects in my source code. Do I need to duplicate the three copies of the license (in different directories)? Or is a single copy of the license sufficent? If a commercial software uses my project where does it need to include the license?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your source code, you only need to keep the MIT license notices of your dependencies intact – you do not have to add them anywhere. If someone builds upon your software, they have to comply with the licenses of their entire dependency tree, and also look at your dependencies.

If you distribute your software in non-source form (e.g. compiled or minified), you still need to keep the notices intact. Then, it would make sense to copy the MIT license notices of your dependencies to a separate file, or to show it in a help message within your software.

The notice that you must preserve consists of both copyright notices and the MIT license text. There are two different variants of the MIT license (Expat and X11) which cannot be exchanged. But where the precise license text is duplicated, you are free to include it only once. For example:

> ### License
>
> > Copyright 2019 your name
> >
> > Your license text
>
> ### Third party software
>
> #### Dependency A
>
> > Copyright 2019 someone
>
> License: MIT
>
> #### Dependency B
>
> > Copyright 2016-2018 someone else
>
> License: MIT
>
> ### Third party license text
>
> #### MIT
>
> > Permission is hereby granted ...

You can also look at how web browsers like Chrome or Firefox do this, which is generally reasonable. E.g. Firefox includes license text once, unless it differs with copyright notices or other additions. This means that MIT-licensed dependencies are each listed with their own license (e.g. “the dependency A license”), whereas standardized license documents like Apache 2 or GPL are only included once.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @amon.. what if my source code is public , do I still need to keep the notices intact?

Comment: @PraveshAgarwal Yes, you must always keep existing notices intact.

Comment: So, is it appropriate/compliant to just link to the text of the MIT license someplace else altogether?

Comment: @einpoklum No, you must retain any existing notices. It's generally accepted to provide the license notice in a document that accompanies the software, but I don't think that merely linking to the notice would be sufficient. What my answer suggests is not linking, but organizing a document with multiple notices in a manner that minimizes duplication. It is inspired by [Debian's COPYRIGHT file format](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/).